# How do I make a WiX installer force VS to install templates?

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I've got a WiX installer that is meant to update VS 2010 templates after installing them. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<CustomAction
      Id="InstallTemplates"
      ExeCommand="&quot;[VISUALSTUDIODIR]devenv.exe&quot; /installvstemplates"
      Directory="VISUALSTUDIODIR"
      Execute="commit"
      Return="check"
      HideTarget="no"
      Impersonate="no"/>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="InstallTemplates" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

In the above, `VISUALSTUDIODIR` refers to the correct location, and templates are correctly deployed. However, it seems that the command does not get called, so no templates are actually installed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiX has built-in functionality to do that. Add a reference to WixVSExtension.dll and add the following authoring:

`<CustomActionRef Id="VS2010InstallVSTemplates" />`

Comment: Ahh, that's nice but it didn't help - the action still isn't being called. Or maybe it's called but has no effect.

Comment: Just checked - it *is* called (but no result ):

MSI (s) (A8:90) [02:57:04:479]: Doing action: VS2010InstallVSTemplates
MSI (s) (A8:90) [02:57:04:479]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 2:57:04: VS2010InstallVSTemplates. 
Action start 2:57:04: VS2010InstallVSTemplates.
VS2010InstallVSTemplates: 
Action ended 2:57:04: VS2010InstallVSTemplates. Return value 1.

Comment: Check later in the log: Those lines are from the script-generation phase, not the execution phase.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that VISUALSTUDIODIR is an actual directory in your MSI package (it's saved in Directory table). This is a requirement for this type of custom action.

Also, try creating an [installation log](http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log/) and search for your custom action to see what happens.